# Is it possible to create a new TFS workspace in PowerShell with Power Tools?

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-power-tools

I am building a function in PowerShell that creates a new Workspace and gets the latest version of the directory specified in addition to some other TFS and file system related tasks.  Right now I'm using a mixture of PowerTools and TFS assemblies to get the job done.  It appears I can do just about everything with Power Tools, except creating a new workspace.  I haven't figured out how to do this without explicitly loading the Team Foundation assemblies.  Is it even possible and if so how?

Here's what I'm doing right now

```
#Install required TFS assemblies
"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client",
"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common",
"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client" |
    ForEach-Object { Add-Type -AssemblyName "$_, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" }

#Install TFS PowerTools snappin for basic tasks
If ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
}

## Set applicable parameters

#Get the TFS server object
$tfs=Get-TfsServer -Name $tfsName

#Get the version control service object
#This is what I want to do with PowerTools - like a new-item or something
$vcs = $tfs.GetService([type]"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer")

#Create a Workspace parameters object
$workspaceParameters = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.CreateWorkspaceParameters -ArgumentList $wsName

#Create the Workspace
$tfsw = $vcs.CreateWorkspace($workspaceParameters)

# Add any working folders that you would defined below
$tfsw.Map($tfsLocation, $localFolder)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only `new` commands in the TFPT snapin is `New-TfsChangeset` and `New-TfsShelveset`.  Is there a reason you can't use `tf.exe workspace /new ...` and `tf.exe workfold ...`?

Comment: No reason at all.  I'm new to PoSh and managing TFS.  The solutions I'm working with are just variations of what I've been able to find with my own limited knowledge.  I was steered toward PowerTools but another user, but so far I'm a bit underwhelmed by what's available with regards to cmdlets.  Are there any prerequisites to the tf.exe methods?  Gotchas I need to be worried about?

Comment: Agreed on TFPT. It is an OK start but it could be doing so much more.  I really miss not having a Get-TfsPermission cmdlet.  We use tf.exe quite a bit in our build & test scripts.  The main pre-req is to have Visual Studio (or VS Team Explorer) installed since that is what installs tf.exe.  Other than that, you need to know that in order to test whether a console exe succeeds, you should check $LASTEXITCODE after invoking the exe.  Also, watch out for parameters that take semi-colon.  That's a statement separator PowerShell.

Comment: For example, this command can cause problems with PowerShell `tf status . /r /workspace:*;johndoe`.  You need to specify it like this `tf status . /r /workspace:*<backtick-char>;johndoe`.  Or if you are on V3 or higher, use the stop-parsing operator e.g. `tf status . /r --% /workspace:*;johndoe`.  Note that with --%, it put's PowerShell into a CMD like parsing mode until the end of the line.